# How to use a value from a text file inside of a Google Chart's javascript guage?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-visualization

Good afternoon!

I'm very new to javascript, php, and HTML, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

So I am trying to create a gauge for a monitoring dashboard I'm creating, and am trying to pull a value from a text file to use in the arrayToDataTable section.

I have a file called `core_mem_usage` that I'm trying to read. Inside of it, it just contains a value, for testing `7.6`.

I've used `<?php include('filename'); ?>` in the past to print a value for memory from a file, but in this case that hasn't worked for me in this case. I've also tried a few other methods, but I haven't been able to get this to work right for me.

Right now, I have this code:

```
<html>
  <head>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
                
        var Trefresh = 3000; //ms
        var php_var = "<?php include('core_mem_usage'); ?>";
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Memory', php_var ],
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 800, height: 240,
          redFrom: 80, redTo: 100,
          yellowFrom:55, yellowTo: 90,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 400px; height: 120px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried setting a variable called `php_var` and setting it to `"<?php include('core_mem_usage'); ?>";` and it's not working. If I remove the line `var php_var = "<?php include('core_mem_usage'); ?>";` and change `php_var` to be hardcoded in as 7.6 it works fine.

Any suggestions on how I can make this work would be amazing!

Besides using php include, I also tried creating a php variable and then attempting to turn that into a js variable like this:
`$php_var = "<?php include('core_mem_usage'); ?>";`
`js_variable_name = "<?php echo $php_var; ?>";`

Comment: The problem is that the value of the js variable `php_var` should be a number, not a string; you may use `var php_var = <?php include('core_mem_usage'); ?>;` (without quotes), or possibly `var php_var = parseFloat("<?php include('core_mem_usage'); ?>");`

Comment: instead of php you could try using ajax from the client side

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @kikon! I could at least get the graph to load with `var php_var = parseFloat("<?php include('core_mem_usage'); ?>");`, however it shows NaN for the value. I tried removing the decimal from the file, so that `core_mem_usage` contains the value 7, and I still get NaN.

Comment: @WhiteHat thank you for your suggestion as well! I've never had any exposure to using ajax, so I'm not entirely where to start with that or how that would work.

Comment: @gerb, you should look in the browser at the page source and see what appears there inside the quotation marks - the page that is served to the browser had already executed the php code, and I suspect something is not OK in that part, since if it were just `parseFloat("7")` it shouldn't give NaN.